# Check if subprocess.Popen creates something

Tags: python, subprocess

I try to write a generic function "SubProcess_function()" I can call for different purposes.

Is there any way to check if Subprocess creates any file or folder ? If it does I want to put them in a temp folder until it's finish, if no, I don't want to do anything.

Here is what I already have (for httrack but imagine I can call what I want):

```
def SubProcess_function(logger, ProcessName, Arguments=" "):
    """
    The subprocess tricks:

    preexec_fn is an arg of subprocess.Popen() which let us catch signals sent to our main program before sending them to subprocesses.
    os.setpgrp allow us to avoid any signal to be sent to subprocess. (No ctrl + C glitches anymore)

    The while True loop let us tryNretry even if indecise user press Ctrl+C and then asks to continue a lot of time.

    Inconvenience: We can't answer to yes/no questions.
    subprocess should be called in quiet mode then.

    Usage: SubProcess_function("MyProcess", (OPTIONAL)listofargs['-r', '-t', '-f', '-m']
    """

    import signal

    tryAgain = True
    while tryAgain == True:
        try:
            logger.info('creating ChildProcess')
            ChildProcess = subprocess.Popen([ProcessName] + Arguments, 
                                            preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
            logger.info('Waiting %s end or KeyboardInterrupt' % ProcessName)
            ChildProcess.wait()
            return None
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logger.warning('KeyboardInterrupt during %s execution !' % ProcessName)
            logger.warning('Send SIGSTOP to %s' % ProcessName)
            os.kill(ChildProcess.pid, signal.SIGSTOP)
            query_stopCont = queryUser("\n\nSeems like you want to exit before end, are you sure ? (Current process: %s)" % ProcessName)
            if query_stopCont == True: #User wants to stop
                logger.info('User wants to stop, send SIGINT to %s' % ProcessName)
                os.kill(ChildProcess.pid, signal.SIGINT)
                tryAgain == False
                query_rm = queryUser("\n\nStopped !\nTemp files may have been created, want to remove it ?")
                if query_rm == True: #User wants to rm temp files
                    logger.info('User wants to stop and rm temp files.')
                    return True
                else: #Users wants to exit and keep temp files
                    logger.info('User wants to stop and keep temp files.')
                    return False
            else: #User wants to continue
                logger.info('User wants to continue')
                continue
        break
```

Which works with

```
def exec_httrack(URL, tempDir, saveDir, tempPath, savePath, logger):
    """
    This function will execute httrack with all parameters.
    tempDir, saveDir, tempPath, savePath are given in main() as a dictionnary.
    """
    import shutil 

    #Execute httrack with -q "quiet" (don't ask any question) and -O "output to" (specifies path for mirror/logfiles cache) -v "verbose"
    httrack_args = [URL, "-q", "-O", tempDir, "-v" "-n" "-p" "-F",
                    "Mozilla 1.0, Sparc, Solaris 23.54.34"]
    logger.warning('launching SubProcess with args= %s', httrack_args)
    processStatus = SubProcess_function(logger, "httrack", httrack_args)

    #Handling execution returns
    #Execution complete, moving from temp to saveDir, delete temp
    if  processStatus is None:
        logger.info('Execution complete !')
        copyDirectory_function(tempPath, savePath, logger)
        logger.info('deleting %s' % tempPath)
        shutil.rmtree(tempPath)
    #Execution cancelled
    #User wants to remove temp files
    elif processStatus is True:
         logger.warning('Execution Cancelled !\nDeleting %s' % tempPath)
         shutil.rmtree(tempPath)
         #if saveDir is empty, it will be removed
         if not os.listdir(savePath):
             logger.warning('Execution Cancelled.')
             logger.info('%s is empty, deleting it' % saveDir)
             shutil.rmtree(savePath)
         print "Temp files cleared !"
    #User wants to quit but keep his temp files
    else:
        logger.info('Execution Cancelled, keeped all temp files in %s' % tempDir)
        print("Temp files saved at: %s" % (tempDir))
```

EDIT: Reformulation:
I want be able to know if the program called in SubProcess_function creates some file or some folder.
In my example, Httrack will.

But I want to be able to use the same function to call another program which won't create anything, then I'll can manage my error messages.
In the current state, if you call Subprocess_function with, for example, Cowsay:

```
args = ["Hello world"]
Subprocess_function(logger, "cowsay", args)
```

And you press ctrl+c it will ask you if you want to remove temp files but that have no sense.

Comment: The details matter. Can you restrict the program to only write to a single directory, or otherwise restricted area of the filesystem? Alternately, can you afford the heavy performance penalty of ptrace-style tracing [as done by `strace`], or the installation and privilege escalation requirements to run a high-performance tracing tool such as sysdig? Is it acceptable to just occasionally poll for open files, even if this means you might miss one if it's created and closed between polls?

Comment: ...because if the answer to all the above is "no", then that's the answer you're going to get to your question as a whole.

Comment: (If you're just worried about cleaning up temporary files, by the way, you might also look at whether your program will honor an environment variable such as `TMPDIR` to generate content in a temporary directory you specify).

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.Popen()` doesn't tell whether the child process has created any files or directories.

There is 3rd-party `psutil.Popen()` that provides more information e.g., there is [`.open_files()` method](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process) which returns a list of files open in the process.

There might be no reliable way other then intercepting system calls that create directories or monitoring the file system that is available to the child process.